# regex with or condition to verify two different patterns?

Tags: java, regex

I need to make a regex where I can verify these two patterns. Basically if any of the string is passed from below two patterns, I should be able to verify it.

- First pattern is - I could have strings like this `tree1` or `tree2`. So basically a number preceded by string `tree`.
- Second pattern is - I can have strings like this `tree1a` or `tree1b` or `tree2a` or `tree2b`. So tree[number][a-z] for this pattern.

I use below regex but it only works with first pattern. How can I make one regex that can handle both the pattern.

```
Pattern patternSet = Pattern.compile("^tree[0-9]$");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an optional `[a-z]?` character class

```
^tree[0-9][a-z]?$
```

- `^` Start of string

  - `tree` Match literally
  - `[0-9]` Match a digit 0-9
  - `[a-z]?` Optionally match a-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dbE49t/1) | [Java demo](http://ideone.com/SOLGRU)

```
Pattern patternSet = Pattern.compile("^tree[0-9][a-z]?$");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should look like so `tree\d[a-z]?`, so your pattern can be :

```
Pattern patternSet = Pattern.compile("tree\\d[a-z]?");
```

If you want more than a digit and more than a letter you can use :

```
Pattern patternSet = Pattern.compile("tree\\d+[a-z]*");
```

the last pattern can match `tree123`, `tree1abc` or `tree123abc`

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by `If you wait more than a digit and more than a letter you can use` with an example?

Comment: @flash I mean if you want to match for example if you want to match `tree123` or `tree1abc` or `tree123abc`